# Log into one page then grab that login and automatically log into other pages without having to type user/pass again

Tags: java, web-deployment

I have 3 different systems, System A, System B, and System C.

System A is my main page, after you log in you can view two tabs for System B and System C.
If you press either System B or System C, a new page opens where you need to enter your user/pass to access a different system.

Both Systems A, B & C share the same login info.

How can I make it so I only need to enter my user/pass in system A and it automatically logs me in System B and C skipping the logging page for those systems so as soon as I click the tab from System B I am in the system not in the login page?

Also, I'm wondering how to deal with inactivity, like if I am logged in System A but decide to press the System B tab to get into System B after 10 hours etc.

I have no idea how to implement this or where to start etc. I code in Java, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about OAuth2 functionality.
You could try to use https://www.keycloak.org/ 
The idea is that you don't login into your app. You login into keycloak (or other OAuth2 provider) and keycloak share information about logged user. 
Example of scenario:
User go to page "A", click login, then is redirec to your keycloak (prepared page that know about page "A"). User is login into keycloak and is redirect to page "A" (now page "A" see autenticated user).

Now user go to page "B". Click login, and is redirect to keycloak (prepared page that know about page "B"). Keycloak know the user, so user don't need to login again. User is redirect to page "B" (now page "B" see autenticated user).
The user may not even notice that he has been on the keycloak page.

There is a lot of tutorials, how to configure keycloak, so I will skip this.